# SAPUI5 - filter table by value calculated with formatter

Tags: sapui5, formatter

I want to filter table by value calculated with formatter. I calculate certain value with formatter and display it in table.

```
<ObjectStatus
     text="{
     path: 'values/',
     formatter: '.formatter.calculate'}"/>
```

My question is if I can filter table by this calculated value and how? Do I need to add custom formating?

Filters are applied in controller:

```
let oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter(sPath, vOperator, vValue1);
aFilters.push(oFilter);
oBinding.filter(aFilters);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the formatted value by accessing the control from the view and calling `getText()`

You'll need to assign an ID, first.

```
<ObjectStatus
     id="objectStatus"
     text="{
     path: 'values/',
     formatter: '.formatter.calculate'}"/>
```

Then in your controller:

```
var sFilterValue = this.getView().byId("objectStatus").getText();
var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter(sPath, vOperator, sFilterValue);
oBinding.filter(oFilter);
```